# Netbeans: Creating a Project Concept versus Opening Files

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, wamp

I'm having a little trouble understanding a couple of concepts.

I am new to Netbeans and using it for PHP development. I am previously using JEdit. In JEdit, I just simply open the file browser and start editing files.

In Netbeans, it wants me to create projects and import files.

My questions are:

- When I import a project, it sets up data files that Netbeans needs and leaves the original directory in tact, correct? I noticed I could open and edit a project and it affected the original.
- Sometimes I like to quickly switch between projects and just want to view the /www/ directory of my wamp server to grab files, look at past projects, etc. Why can't I simply do this? (must I always import projects to see my /www/ folder)
- What is the point between creating a project versus just opening files?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The point of creating a project vs just opening files in an editor is that Netbeans knows that all these files go together. They are part of the same project. That allows you, for instance, to refactor function names or class names and have Netbeans automatically apply the changes everywhere those are used within your project.

If you create a project from existing sources, those existing files will be the ones you're editing. If you have your files under version control, you can simply create a Netbeans project in the directory where you checked out your code. You can then do commits and all from within Netbeans.